# Git lists same file modified and not staged for commit?

Tags: git

For some reason Git is telling me I have a file which is both "to be committed" and also "not staged for commit"? This doesn't make sense:

```
% git status 
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   modified:   Dir1/Dir2/filename.cpp
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   modified:   Dir1/Dir2/filename.cpp
```

`Dir1`, `Dir2` and `filename.cpp` are definitely all the same file. I had to add `filename.cpp` back again to  get it to appear as a change to be committed (after it was originally in the repository). About the only thing that may have caused the problem was that I stashed, `pull --rebase`, then popped the `stash`? `.gitignore` does not list `Dir1`, `Dir2` or `filename.cpp` anywhere and the patterns don't suggest they would catch this file?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: looks like you modified it after adding it, add it again and it should be fine.

Comment: Please read about [the basics](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics#The-Three-States) before using a tool in production.

Comment: Though the question may not be perfectly phrased, the output itself clearly shows an indeed very confusing issue with git, i.e. listing a file under "to be committed" and also "not staged for commit", for which a cheap "RTFM" is definitely not the optimal solution.

Answer (score 37):

It means that you made a change to `filename.cpp`, added that change (with `git add`), then made another change that has not yet been added.

The "changes to be committed" part means that Git has updated its index with a change. When you run `git commit`, the changes to the index will be used to create the new commit object.

The "changes not staged" part shows the difference between the index and your working copy.

You can reproduce what you're seeing like so:

- Edit filename.cpp
- Run `git status`. You'll see "changes not staged".
- Run `git add filename.cpp`
- Run `git status`. You'll see "changes to be committed".
- Edit filename.cpp again
- Run `git status`. You'll see both "changes not staged" and "changes to be committed".

Does that make sense? It's always a little tricky explaining how Git works.

Comment: also note: you can only add a file once to a commit group.  If you change it again after adding it; those changes will not be included in the commit. To include all new changes in the commit you must "git reset -file-" and then "git add -file-" to bring the committed copy up to date

Comment: I run `git add file.java`, run `git status` right after and it still shows the file on both "changes not staged" and "changes to be committed", very confused

Answer (score 12):

In CVS, SVN, BZR, and no doubt a dozen other tools, once a file is added that means it'll be included in the next commit.

Not so GIT.

In git you don't "add a file", you "add a change" (sometimes it's called "stage a change").

If you change a file twice you have to "add" it twice.

Comment: That's right. I would just add that you can stage just a line(s) from the file or even some part(s) (it's called chunk). It's an awesome feature, I'm using it very often, for example when I made more (logically unrelated) changes in the same file and I want to split them into separate commits.

Answer (score 5):

If you modify a file, add it and them remodify the file, you'll get this behaviour. When you do a git add, it adds the changes up to that point, and commiting after that without re-adding only commits the first set of added changes.

```
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

matthewfarwell (master)
$ vi foo.txt <-- add lines 1,2,3 here

matthewfarwell (master)
$ git add foo.txt

matthewfarwell (master)
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   foo.txt
#

matthewfarwell (master)
$ vi foo.txt <-- add lines 4,5,6, here

matthewfarwell (master)
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   foo.txt
#
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   foo.txt
#
```

So if I commit now, only the lines 1,2,3 will be commited.