# same file displayed in "not staged for commit" and "to be committed" since the file isnt edited

Tags: git, git-push, git-commit

Hi I have a problem with Git and hope somebody can give me some help.

```
             /`\
            / : |
   _.._     | '/
 /`    \    | /
|  .-._ '-"` (
|_/   /   o  o\
      |  =  () )= FOLLOW THE WHITE RABBIT!
       \  '--`/
       / ---<`
      | ,    \\
      | |     \\_
      / ;     |.__)
     (_/.-.   ;
    { `|   \_/
     '-\   / |
        | /  |
       /  \  '-.
       \__|----'

Last login: Wed Feb 19 13:28:48 2014 from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Logged in and doin some things

```
user@matrix:~$ cd htdocs/blabla.de/
user@matrix:~/htdocs/blabla.de$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

user@matrix:~/htdocs/blabla.de$ git pull origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/home/any/path/.ssh/id_rsa':
From ssh://git.ownserver.de:22/any/project
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.

user@matrix:~/htdocs/blabla.de$ git checkout dev
Switched to branch 'dev'

user@matrix:~/htdocs/blabla.de$ git pull origin dev
Enter passphrase for key '/home/any/path/.ssh/id_rsa':
From ssh://git.ownserver.de:22/any/project
 * branch            dev        -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.

user@matrix:~/htdocs/blabla.de$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
```

created my new Branch for some style changes

```
user@matrix:~/htdocs/blabla.de$ git checkout -b cal/style
Switched to a new branch 'cal/style'
```

Change styles with IDE

```
user@matrix:~/htdocs/blabla.de$ git status
# On branch cal/style
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   fileadmin/templates/css/reiseseiten.css
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Added changed File to Index

```
user@matrix:~/htdocs/blabla.de$ git add fileadmin/templates/css/reiseseiten.css
```

Commit Changes

```
user@matrix:~/htdocs/blabla.de$ git commit -m '11715 Hintergrundfarbe bei Modulen (CAL)'
[cal/style aada6a3] 11715 Hintergrundfarbe bei Modulen (CAL)
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
 mode change 100644 => 100755 fileadmin/templates/css/reiseseiten.css
```

Switch to master

```
user@matrix:~/htdocs/blabla.de$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
```

Merge Changes into master

```
user@matrix:~/htdocs/blabla.de$ git merge cal/style
Updating b3260c3..aada6a3
Fast-forward
 fileadmin/templates/css/reiseseiten.css |    6 +++---
 1 file changed, 3 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
 mode change 100644 => 100755 fileadmin/templates/css/reiseseiten.css
```

Push into repository -> Without Errors

```
user@matrix:~/htdocs/blabla.de$ git push origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/home/any/path/.ssh/id_rsa':
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 554 bytes, done.
Total 6 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://git@git.ownserver.de:22/any/project.git
   b3260c3..aada6a3  master -> master
```

Doin some other shit in Firebug (not in any File of this GitRepo)

20 Minutes later check status of the project (THIS IS ONLY A LOCAL PROJECT, ONLY I HAVE ACCESS)

```
user@matrix:~/htdocs/blabla.de$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   fileadmin/templates/css/reiseseiten.css
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   fileadmin/templates/css/reiseseiten.css
#
```

I looked for the commit time (17:18) and inside the filesystem for the last-change time of the File.

Same Time for both, so nobody changed this file after commit

```
user@matrix:~/htdocs/blabla.de$ git log
commit aada6a375bce002c26910afea6024c40c6f754a1
Author: Christian user <user@me.de>
Date:   Wed Feb 19 17:18:14 2014 +0100

    11715 Hintergrundfarbe bei Modulen (CAL)
```

Think thats a sideeffect and already done with a fetch

```
user@matrix:~/htdocs/blabla.de$ git fetch
Enter passphrase for key '/home/any/path/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

But iam wrong thats no sideeffect, BUT WHAT IST THIS?

```
user@matrix:~/htdocs/blabla.de$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   fileadmin/templates/css/reiseseiten.css
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   fileadmin/templates/css/reiseseiten.css
#
```

Looked inside the Diff and see that are the changes of my last commit.

Whats wrong?

Comment: What do you see in `git diff` and `git diff --staged`?

Comment: I see my last changes, but they are commited and pushed into the repository by merging my feature branch into the master.

Comment: My question was really precise. You should not see the same thing in `git diff` and `git diff --staged`, and I really would like to know the answer.

Comment: I also wonder if you are using `git-new-workdir`. It can be relevant.

Comment: @lrineau: i see the same diff on git diff and git diff --staged

Comment: And i dont use git-new-workdir

Comment: I cannot understand how `git diff` and `git diff --staged` can see the exact same thing. Maybe they can show one patch and its opposite patch, but they cannot display the same patch.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be similar to this question: [Git lists same file modified and not staged for commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676173/git-lists-same-file-modified-and-not-staged-for-commit)

The same file can be marked as `Changes to be committed` *and* `Changes not staged for commit` if you made changes to the file, added the file with `git add`, and then made additional changes after that.